# Show that there is such function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

This was a question on a past midterm I could not solve.

Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ and suppose that $0 \leq f(x) \leq 2$ for all $ x  \in  [0,1]$. Show that there is some $t \in [0,1]$ such that $f(t) = 3t$.

Comment: Is this supposed to be $f(t) = 3t$? We don't know anything about $f$ outside of $[0,1]$

Comment: Yes it is, my apologies.

Comment: What do you know about continuous functions?

Comment: Can you think of a particular theorem that might be helpful?

Comment: This was given on the midterm which had the units of derivatives and limits covered, and from what was given to us nothing applied to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this rephrasing of the question, $0\leq f(x) \leq 2$ on $[0,1]$. Prove it intersects with $g(x)=3x$ on $[0,1]$.

Consider this: if $g(x)\neq f(x)$, then $f(x)>g(x)$ or $f(x)<g(x)$.

Consider the first. Impossible, because $f(x>2/3)>2$ and $g(x)\leq2$.

Consider the latter. If $f(0)>0$, then $f(x)>g(x)$, which cannot hold for the entire interval. Otherwise, $f(x)=g(x)$, and $f(0)=g(0)=0$.

Because $f(x)$ cannot be greater or less than $g(x)$ for the entire $[0,1]$, it must equal $g(x)$ at some point on the closed interval.

In other words, there is a $t$ such that $f(t)=3t$ and $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f (0)=0$ then $t=0$ and $f (t)=0=3*0$ solves the condition.

Otherwise if $f (0)\ne 0$ then $f (0) > 0=3*0$ and $f (1)\le 2 <3*1$.

Consider $g (x)=f (x)-3x $.  At $t=0$ $f (t)-3t=f (0)>0$.  At $t=1$, $f (t)=f (1)-3 \le 2-3 <0$.

So by intermediate value theorem there is a $t\in [0,1] $ wher $g (t)=0$ and so $f (t)=3 (t) $.